# Save from LyX to PNG

Tags: lyx, pstricks, png

I have a LyX file with a PSTricks picture. Currently, when I want to convert it to a PNG image, I save the file as PS, then open the PS in gimp, then save it as PNG. Is there a way to save to PNG directly from LyX?

Comment: thta's possible. You can create a LyX layout for the documentclass `standalone`, then you can configure it to create a png output

Comment: "You can create a LyX layout for the documentclass standalone" - how can I do this?

Comment: copy the `article.layout` from (on Linux) `usr/share/lyx/layouts/` into your local LyX directory (on Linux) `~/.lyx/layouts/` and edit the line with `\DeclareLayTeXClass{article}`. Change `article` to `standalone` and then rename the file to `standalone.layout` and run from within LyX the option `Reconfigure`. Restart LyX and then the `standalone` class should be available. Read the documentation of `standalone` how PSTricks examples should be used and how you can a cropped pdf or png output.

Comment: Is there a reason that you prefer to use PNG instead of PS? Since PS is a vector format, it is better at preserving image quality.

Comment: @Liviu I want to include the PNG in a presentation, and PNG is better supported by presentation software.

Comment: Well, you could always use LyX to create Beamer presentations, and then (E)PS would be the format of choice. But if you must stick to MS PowerPoint or LibO Impress, then you could define a Postscript -> PNG converter in LyX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must use MS PowerPoint or LibO Impress to create the presentation, then you could define a `Postscript -> PNG` or `EPS -> PNG` converter in LyX (I'm not sure which one's more appropriate so feel free to experiment) using ImageMagick's `convert`.

In practice this might be easier as the converters seem to be already in place, with only minor tweaks needed: in 2.0.6 try `Tools > Prefs > File > Formats > PNG` then check `Document format` and `Show in export menu` (also consider setting the `Viewer` to something less heavy than GIMP). Then you should be able to `File > Export > PNG`.

Does it work?