# Exporting Lyx Math Equation to PNG

Tags: math-mode, lyx, export

I wish to create some maths formula for use with mind mapping application iThoughts. If I define the equation in Lyx then export I can choose HTML and one the files is a nice PNG of the equation, but I don't want all the other files created. Is there a way to directly export to a PNG file.

Comment: It seems like you're more interested in something like the [Online LaTeX equation editor](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php). From there you can export an image of the equation in PNG format.

Comment: what command driven graphics tool chains do you have e.g. GS Magik since the easiest is to use one you are familiar with see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151360/170109

Comment: If you can do SVG, that'll be even nicer!

Comment: Another option that’s a little more complicated but more general: write the equations as small documents with `\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}`, compile to PDF, then convert to an image with a program such as ImageMagick.

Comment: Thanks Werner - Prompted me to look for a similar app available for my Mac and found MathMagic lite which seems to do the job

Comment: @KeithSloan Perhaps Export/View EPS (cropped) is what you're looking for? I think it was created for the purpose you have in mind. See, e.g., https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX.NewInLyX21#cropped